# In Java, how can I access the main class dynamically?

Tags: java

I am trying to access a variable of the main class. The problem is that I want to make my code completely modular so that I can build on it and create a library. The problem I am having is that in order access the variable I must use the name of the main class as such:

```
    // this is in the main class which we will call "MyPlugin"
    public class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin {
        public static String compath = "CommandFileName";

        @Override
        public void onEnable() {
            this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyListener(this), this);
        }
    }

    // this is in the listener class which we will call "MyListener"
    public MyListener(Plugin instance) {
        Plugin plugin = instance;
        path = MyPlugin.compath;    // <-- the problem...
```

My first thought was that I should be able to simply do this:

```
    path = plugin.compath;
```

however for some reason the plugin object does not contain the compath variable.
Is there a way to access a variable of the main class without using its name?

Now more indepth for those who may like to think around the purpose. MyListener is going to reference a config file of type yml. For whatever reason, the name of the key's in the config yml file may be different in future. My idea was to put the names in the main class so they could be referenced by MyListener. Such an approach would more centralize the list of names and prevent extensive changes to multiple classes in future.

Comment: pass it as a parameter in the constructor? or create a method that takes it as a parameter?

Comment: Is `plugin` of class `Plugin` or class `MyPlugin`? because `class Plugin` probably does not have a `compath`

Comment: AS @JeD said, Plugin class (that seems to be  a super class of MyPlugin) doesn't know about compath. You have a scope confusion. However, static variables should be acceded with the class name where was defined. In books, you'll find out that like: class atrributes

Comment: Exactly correct Jordy, however I do not wish to use the name of the class it was defined in as it defeats the purpose of OO and I would have many such reverences to change if I wish to use the code in another plugin with a different name for the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to declare a getter in the `JavaPlugin` API.

There are two things that you have done in your initial design that are making your task complicated: you have made the variable `static` and you have made it `public`.  Both of these are bad OO design:

- Static variables are bad for testability and can't be used polymorphically (or "dynamically" as you phrase it).
- Public variables are bad for abstraction.  (Especially non-final ones!)

Anyhow, this is how I would implement this:

```
public abstract class MyPluginBase extends JavaPlugin {
    public abstract String getCompath();
    ....
}

public class MyPlugin extends MyPluginBase {
    @Override
    public String getCompath() {
        return "CommandFileName";
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(
               new MyListener(this), this);
    }
}

public MyListener(MyPluginBase instance) {
    path = instance.getCompath();
    ...
}
```

Comment: JavaPlugin is imported, I do not know where to alter this and would probably prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: You can make your own subclass of `JavaPlugin` which defines the `getCompath()` method; see the edits.

Comment: Now that may just work. Its a pitty that I cant just create a pointer to the class by using its name stored in a string variable. Something like "ClassPointer mainclass = new ClassPointer(classname)" and then just use mainclass.compath

Comment: Well, you can't.  The "best" you could do would be something horrible using reflection.  Seriously, Java is an OO language, and you should be trying to use it in an OO fashion.

Comment: Yeah, trying but the portability of my code is suffering.

Comment: Ermm ... if writing your Java code in an OO fashion is affecting portability, then you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: So, still needing to explicitly reference a class by its name. I don't think this is going to happen.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?  My solution does not involve referencing a class by its name.  Perhaps you don't understand it.

Comment: public MyListener(MyPluginBase <-- Everytime I wish to re-use this class, I will need to change both the name of the package and this reference to "MyPluginBase". If I try to import it into another project, it will be also looking for the "MyPluginBase" class.

Comment: No ... you make `MyPluginBase` the common base class for all of your plugins!

Comment: I can see where your going however if I share the library, it will break as soon as anyone tries to use it as this is not a common standard. I have seen people use Main, MainClass, and even like me, the name of their plugin its self.

Comment: This answer fits best. Although it is not the solution I was looking for, it does solve half of the problem. 

It has become apparent that what I want is simply impossible in java.

Thank you Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

pass it as a parameter:

```
public MyListener(Plugin instance, String path) {
    Plugin plugin = instance;
    this.path = path;    // <-- the problem...
}

 public class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin {
    public static String compath = "CommandFileName";

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MyListener(this, compath), this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, that would work but is somewhat of an adhoc solution. There will be many such variables and possibly many other classes which will need to access them. This could create very messy code.

Comment: @Stuperfied use java reflection

Comment: I admit I could put them all in a list and pass that however I should not have to. They are all contained in the main class and I am able to access them but there must be a way to avoid using the name of the class. Something like " Hey, you know that class thats in control?, I want something in there..."

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted

```
public MyListener(MyPlugin instance) {
        MyPlugin plugin = instance;
        path = plugin.compath;
```

The problem is that you use `Plugin` instead of `MyPlugin`

Comment: Exactly the problem, I don't want to use the identifier "MyPlugin". I would rather use something like this.plugin.getName() so the code is more portable but I cant even get that to work.

Comment: Obviously not. Plugin does not have the variable you are looking for... @Stuperfied

Comment: And it seems there is no other way to access "MyPlugin" without using its name.